# Google resource manager get all exceptions - Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

im making a python script that can manage my google projects.
im having a insue with one part
when i try to exclude the project its can return to me many errors.

i did a peace of code to get this exception:

```
        try:
            # Initialize request argument(s)

            request = DeleteProjectRequest(
                name=project,
            )
            self.project_manager.delete_project(request=request)

        except PermissionDenied as exc:
            # GCP returns PermissionDenied whether we actually does
            # not have permissions to perform the get_project call
            # or when the project does not exist. Due to this reason,
            # the PermissionDenied exception catch won't be deterministic.
            logger.error(f"Project '{project_id}' does not exist", exc)
            return False
```

i need to get the error message of all types of errors
i changed `except PermissionDenied as exc:` for `except Exception as exc:`
and it works but i need to call the logger only if the error is `PermissionDenied` and in all cases i need to call another function passing the message as parameter like it `return_to_db(error_message)`

my question is. how can i run only the logger if the error is `PermissionDenied`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a condition of the instance type of the current exception in `Python`, example :

```py
        try:
            # Initialize request argument(s)

            request = DeleteProjectRequest(
                name=project,
            )
            self.project_manager.delete_project(request=request)

        except Exception as exc:
            if isinstance(exc, PermissionDenied):
               logger.error(f"Project '{project_id}' does not exist", exc)
            
        return False
```

As expected, the `logger` is executed only if the exception instance is `PermissionDenied`.

Answer (score 3):

You can also catch multiple Exceptions by adding additional blocks, though it will choose the first `isinstance()` match (so if you put `Exception` first, it will be selected instead, while `TypeError` would be continued past)

```py
try:
    self.project_manager.delete_project(
        request=DeleteProjectRequest(name=project))
except PermissionDenied as exc:
    # GCP returns PermissionDenied whether we actually does
    # not have permissions to perform the get_project call
    # or when the project does not exist. Due to this reason,
    # the PermissionDenied exception catch won't be deterministic.
    logger.error(f"Project '{project_id}' does not exist", exc)
except Exception:
    # FIXME other handling to go here
    pass  # fall to return False
else:  # didn't raise
    return True
# opportunity for finally: block here too

# if any Exception was raised, continue to return False
return False
```